# Appending an element to a list of arrays (in the most concise idiomatic way)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code:

```
alist = [[0], [1], [2]]
blist = [-1, 0, 1]

for a, b in zip(alist, blist):
    a.append(b)
```

> output is [[0, -1], [1, 0], [2, 1]]

It works, but is there a way to remove the loop entirely?

Comment: *remove the loop entirely* or hide it behind some construct?

Comment: Honestly I like the way you wrote this and I wouldn't advice changing it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine IMHO. It's readable, concise and makes it clear that you want to modify `alist` in place.

If you want to avoid any explicit loop, you could work with numpy arrays and use [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]])
b = np.array([2, 3, 4])
np.column_stack([a, b])
```

It outputs:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: Importing numpy to avoid a for loop. This sounds so overpowered.

Comment: @Olivier: Importing numpy to work with 1-D and 2-D arrays sounds like a good idea to me. You're right though, I'll add a note.

Comment: I'm not against it at all, it's just somewhat funny.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> alist = [[0], [1], [2]]
>>> blist = [-1, 0, 1]
>>> [a + [b] for a, b in zip(alist, blist)]
[[0, -1], [1, 0], [2, 1]]
```

will do what you want (without modifying alist), though it's not pretty

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to have a list of tuples as a result, I find this solution very readable.

```
>>> alist = [[0], [1], [2]]
>>> blist = [-1, 0, 1] 
>>> import itertools as it
>>> list(zip(it.chain(*alist), blist))
[(0, -1), (1, 0), (2, 1)]
```

If you must have a list of lists:

```
list(list(el) for el in zip(it.chain(*alist), blist))
```

Basically, I am unpacking the variable `alist` into positional arguments, which I then pass to [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). This results in a flat list `[0, 1, 2]`. After that, you can simple `zip` the two lists and get the desired result without using a for loop. It is not the fastest but a valid, possible solution.